# Erro ao tentar usar retorno da função no if

Tags: php

Estou usando o **Laravel** com o layout **AdminLTE**

Fiz essa função no arquivo `config/adminlte.php` para tentar definir quando aparece o menu no sidebar:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

function teste()
{
    $personal = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

    if($personal->nivel == 1) return true;
    else return false;
}

if(teste()){
    $painel = 'PAINEL ADMINISTRATIVO';
    $menu =  [
        'text'       => 'Usuários Cadastrados',
        'url'  => 'users',
        'icon' => 'users',
    ];
    $menu2 = [
        'text'       => 'Cadastrar Novo Usuário',
        'url'  => 'users/create',
        'icon' => 'user-plus',
    ];
}else{
    $painel = '';
    $menu = '';
    $menu2 = '';
}
```

Porém esta me retornando este erro:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in D:\wamp64\www\sisFarmacia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752 Stack trace: #0
    D:\wamp64\www\sisFarmacia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(752): ReflectionClass->__construct('view') #1 
    D:\wamp64\www\sisFarmacia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view') #2 
    D:\wamp64\www\sisFarmacia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(586): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view', Array) #3
     D:\wamp64\www\sisFarmacia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(732): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('view', Array) #4 
    D:\wamp64\www\sisFarmacia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('view', Array) #5 
    D:\wamp64\www\sisFarmacia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(965): app('Illuminate\\C in D:\wamp64\www\sisFarmacia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 752
```

Caso troque o `if(teste())` por `if(1)` o sistema roda certo exibindo o menu, `if(0)` e não exibe o menu

Pelos testes que fiz acredito que o problema esteja no `Auth::user()->id` mas não entendo o porque

Comment: Vi algumas questões a respeito do erro e muitos citam que valores no arquivo .env não podem conter espaços. Já tentou verificar isso?

Comment: O sistema funciona perfeitamente se no lugar do if(teste()) eu colocar if(1), é ai que aparece o erro

Comment: @ÐvÐ editei para explicar melhor a situação

Comment: Veja se possui Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider listado nos providers no arquivo config/app.php.

Comment: Tem esta outra resposta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34591724/1377664

Comment: @ÐvÐ nenhuma delas resolve, o problema está na chamada do `Auth::user()->id`, só retirar ele que funciona ok, coloco ele retorna o erro, e testei utilizando outras lógicas onde este é chamado em posições diferentes no código e o mesmo erro